# maintaining json schema for webhook/push notification

Tags: json, rest, push-notification

I am working on a requirement to build a **PUSH API,** for sending (POST) "data" to subscribed customers in JSON format.

At this initial stage, the attempt is to be build a comprehensive JSON Schema that would satisfy the requirement for all known customers(customer would generate model classes using published schema and be able to consumer data POSTed to their REST endpoint).

But, thinking of future, when more customers come onboard etc., there is possibility to add new fields to JSON schema (which existing customer may NOT be interested in).

Trying to find a good way to handle the situation (like to avoid creating different schema versions and also per customer).

Appreciate any suggestions/thoughts?